# How to use multiple mps devices in M1 Mac for PyTorch

Tags: python, macos, pytorch, gpu, metal

I am running a transformer model and It will be great if I can use multiple GPUs to parallelise the load. So I wanted to know if M1 Mac has multiple mps devices. Currently my code only uses mps:0 - thats what I get from torch.device() code. I am wondering if I can have mps:0 , mps:1 , .. till how many ever mps devices my Mac has to run the PyTorch code.

I want a Metal and Pytorch Equivalent of the following code for CUDA:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(self.args.gpu) if not self.args.use_multi_gpu else self.args.devices
device = torch.device('cuda:{}'.format(self.args.gpu))
print('Use GPU: cuda:{}'.format(self.args.gpu))
```

My understanding of the above code is that , when you set os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] , it automatically parallelises the work among all visible GPUs. I want to do the same in Metal/ M1 Mac

I am trying to reproduce - https://github.com/Thinklab-SJTU/Crossformer with multiple GPUs in M1 Mac

Comment: There’s only one GPU in any Apple Silicon Mac so I’m not even sure what you are asking here

Comment: I thought there are multiple GPUs.  I thought that because I was able to have tensors like mps:0 mps:1 and even mps:100 . So I thought there are more devices and I am just using only one. Thanks for confirming there is only one GPU. So , if all the tensors are in mps:0 only , still I will be utilising the maximum compute from the GPU , I hope .

Comment: But , can you see this Metal Documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/performing_calculations_on_a_gpu#3544865 This says macOS can have multiple GPUs

Comment: An Intel Mac can have multiple GPUs, but as I said, any of the M-family chips have exactly one.